# Valid from and valid to or until?

Tags: prepositions

Would `valid to` make sense when refering to an expiration date?
I've got this text right now:

```
Valid from: 01/10/2014
Valid to: 10/10/2014
```

It doesn't sound correct. Should it be `until`?

In which cases can I use `to` and not `until`?

Comment: Whichever you pick, please don't use the construction found in some contest ad disclaimers: 'Offer ends October 10th or while supplies last'.

Comment: Why not, @JimMack?

Comment: Seriously? "Offer ends...while supplies last" was common (and much mocked) a few years ago, from fast food joints with promotional giveaways.

Comment: Didn't know that. However, why was it mocked? It makes sense to me.

Comment: Because it's contradictory. The offer *continues* or *is valid* while supplies last. It *ends* when supplies are exhausted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both "to" and "until" can imply that the item is not valid on the end-date specified, but only up to that date.

"Valid through" would imply that it was valid through that final end-date, and eliminates any possible misinterpretation.